# cntml- server is listening on the localhost interface only

Tags: server, vagrant, virtualbox

I have a server set up that is running cntml and I would like a virtual machine box that I created to be able to upstream the proxy through the server.I keep getting that the port denies me from my virtual box. How do I configure it so I can connect via all interfaces? virtual box was created using vagrant.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: how do you start your cntlm ?